# How do I restart a program based on user input?

Tags: python

I'm trying to restart a program using an if-test based on the input from the user.

This code doesn't work, but it's approximately what I'm after:

```
answer = str(raw_input('Run again? (y/n): '))

if answer == 'n':
   print 'Goodbye'
   break
elif answer == 'y':
   #restart_program???
else:
   print 'Invalid input.'
```

What I'm trying to do is:

- if you answer y - the program restarts from the top
- if you answer n - the program ends (that part works)
- if you enter anything else, it should print 'invalid input. please enter y or n...' or something, and ask you again for new input.

I got really close to a solution with a "while true" loop, but the program either just restarts no matter what you press (except n), or it quits no matter what you press (except y). Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
while True:
    # main program
    while True:
        answer = str(input('Run again? (y/n): '))
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        print("invalid input.")
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
        break
```

The inner while loop loops until the input is either `'y'` or `'n'`. If the input is `'y'`, the while loop starts again (`continue` keyword skips the remaining code and goes straight to the next iteration). If the input is `'n'`, the program ends.

Answer (score 48):

This line will unconditionally restart the running program from scratch:

```
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
```

One of its advantage compared to the remaining suggestions so far is that the program itself will be read again.

This can be useful if, for example, you are modifying its code in another window.

Comment: This doesn't work on windows if Python is installed in a path with spaces

Comment: @Beefster this can be solved by instead using `subprocess.call(sys.executable + ' "' + os.path.realpath(__file__) + '"')`

Comment: @EladAvron The problem with that solution is that it creates an endless chain of subprocesses which will eventually cause the os to run out of memory. I'm not sure what happens at that point.

Comment: @Beefster That depends on the use case, but that is indeed a possibility. Maybe there's a way to close all previous subprocesses when opening a new one, but I haven't looked into it.

Comment: @EladAvron That's not really how subprocesses work. I think there might be a way to disown them from python and then kill the current process, but then that takes away control from the shell.

Then again, subprocesses probably work differently on windows. I'm thinking in Linux mode right now.

Comment: @Beefster I admittedly know nothing about them, so I just tried stuff until I found something that works. Wouldn't surprise me if it's totally the wrong way to do it, sorry.

Comment: This solves the problem of not being able to have a space in the python installation path.
`os.execl(sys.executable, '"{}"'.format(sys.executable), *sys.argv)`

Comment: @EladAvron on your program you can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html this funtion and inside atexit with a global variable condition, you can put the restart code and just simply set the global variable True and exit() whenever you wanna restart. this may help you a bit with the loop issue.

Comment: @JustinG Now it'd be better still if you used f-strings. Instead of `'"{}"'.format(sys.executable)`, you can use `f'"{sys.executable}"'`.

Comment: @jlliagre subprocess.call specifically is bad because it spawns a subshell and waits for it to complete, whereas os.execl *replaces* the process.

Comment: @Beefster My mistake, you are absolutely right. I read too fast. I thought your comment was referring to my reply, not Elad Avron's comment. Deleting mine.

Answer (score 3):

Using one while loop:

```
In [1]: start = 1
   ...: 
   ...: while True:
   ...:     if start != 1:        
   ...:         do_run = raw_input('Restart?  y/n:')
   ...:         if do_run == 'y':
   ...:             pass
   ...:         elif do_run == 'n':
   ...:             break
   ...:         else: 
   ...:             print 'Invalid input'
   ...:             continue
   ...: 
   ...:     print 'Doing stuff!!!'
   ...: 
   ...:     if start == 1:
   ...:         start = 0
   ...:         
Doing stuff!!!

Restart?  y/n:y
Doing stuff!!!

Restart?  y/n:f
Invalid input

Restart?  y/n:n

In [2]:
```

Comment: Ok, Ok.  Fair enough.  You don't *need* 2 `while` loops -- But I still think it's cleaner that way :) -- I actually liked my decorator solution, but that might be a little advanced for a question like this ...

Comment: @mgilson -- Maybe. But the decorator *certainly is* pretty neat, +1.

Comment: Good utilization of while loop

Answer (score 3):

You can do this simply with a function. For example:

```
def script():
    # program code here...
    restart = raw_input("Would you like to restart this program?")
    if restart == "yes" or restart == "y":
        script()
    if restart == "n" or restart == "no":
        print "Script terminating. Goodbye."
script()
```

Of course you can change a lot of things here. What is said, what the script will accept as a valid input, the variable and function names. You can simply nest the entire program in a user-defined function (Of course you must give everything inside an extra indent) and have it restart at anytime using this line of code: `myfunctionname()`. More on this [here.](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html)

Comment: Of course, let me know if this fails and I will try to fix

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy do this

```
while True:

       #do something

       again = input("Run again? ")

       if 'yes' in again:
              continue
       else:
              print("Good Bye")
              break
```

Basically, in this the while loop will run the program again and again because while loops run if the condition is `True` so we have made  the condition true and as you know `True` is always true and never false. So, will not stop then after this the main part comes here first we will take input from the user whether they want to continue the program or not then we will say that if user says yes i want to continue then the `continue` keyword will bring the loop to the top again and will run the program again too and if the user says something else or you can do it in another way if you want to only quit the program if user says no then just add this

```
elif 'no' in again:
       print("Good Bye")
       break
else:
       print("Invalid Input")
```

this will look that if there is the 'no' word in the input and if there is then it will break the loop and the program will quit

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code may offer a solution to the question, but adding explanation as to how it works will help other users interpret it more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun way to do it with a [decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

```
def restartable(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        answer = 'y'
        while answer == 'y':
            func(*args,**kwargs)
            while True:
                answer = raw_input('Restart?  y/n:')
                if answer in ('y','n'):
                    break
                else:
                    print "invalid answer"
    return wrapper

@restartable
def main():
    print "foo"

main()
```

Ultimately, I think you need 2 while loops.  You need one loop bracketing the portion which prompts for the answer so that you can prompt again if the user gives bad input.  You need a second which will check that the current answer is `'y'` and keep running the code until the answer isn't `'y'`.