# Python: How to end program in a loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, break

The Python program I have made is menu based and requires inputs from the user to navigate around the program.

I have placed a `while` loop in order to take the user back to the beginning menu in order to perform the task but one of the options which is "Press 0 to Quit" would just restart the loop and not end the program. Below is the code:

```
terms = {"ALU":"Arithmetic Logic Unit", "CPU":"Central Processing Unit", "GPU":"Graphics Processing Unit"}
while True:
    print(
    """
    Computing Terminology

    0 - Quit
    1 - Look Up a Term
    2 - Add a Term
    3 - Redefine  a Term
    4 - Delete a Term
    5 - Display All Terms
    """
    )
    menu = input("Choice: ")
    print()
    while menu != "0":
       if menu == "1":
            print("\n")
            term = input("Type in a term you wish to see: ")
            if term in terms:
                definition = terms[term]
                print("\n")
                print(term, "means", definition, "\n")
                break
            else:
                print("This term does not exist.\n")
                break
        elif menu == "2":
            term = input("What term would you like to add?: ")
            if term not in terms:
                print("\n")
                definition = input("What's the definition?: ")
                terms[term] = definition
                print("\n")
                print(term, "has been added.\n")
                break
            else:
                print("\n")
                print("Term already exists, try redefining it instead.\n")
                break
        elif menu == "3":
            term = input("Which term do you want to redefine?: ")
            if term in terms:
                definition = input("What's the new definition?: ")
                terms[term] = definition
                print("\n")
                print(term, "has been redefined.\n")
                break
            else:
                print("\n")
                print("That term doesn't exist, try adding it instead.\n")
                break
        elif menu == "4":
            term = input("Which term would you like to delete?: ")
            if term in terms:
                del terms[term]
                print("\n")
                print("The term has been deleted.\n")
                break
            else:
                print("\n")
                print("This term doesn't exist.\n")
                break
        elif menu == "5":
            print("\n")
            print("Terms available are: ")
            for term in terms:
                print("\n", term, "\n")
        else:
            print("\n")
            print("Sorry, but", menu, "is not a valid choice.\n")
            break

print("\n")
input("Press any key to exit.") #if user enters 0 I want the program to end here.
```

Comment: It might personal preference but I would avoid using strings for input if the choices are going to be numbers. To me it makes more sense to have them be `int`s to avoid any confusion on whether or not you need quotes down the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I always do

```
def print_menu():
    print('What would you like to do: ')
    print('1. Retrieve data')
    print('2. Store Data')
    print('3. Exit')

while True:
    print_menu()
    choice = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if choice == 1:
        #blah
    elif choice == 2:
        #blah blah
    elif choice == 3:
        break
```

Comment: it works - but runs through all if's every time - use elif

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Updating code now.

Answer (score 3):

Put `menu = input("Choice: ")` **inside** of your while loop.

Comment: I did this but it will just come up with a `Traceback` error when I run it. I then added `menu = None` in the first `while` loop and the program will run but only for "0" to have the response `"Sorry, but 0 is not a valid choice."`.

Comment: If you want `menu` to equal and empty string you could just use `menu= ''`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm skimming your code too quickly, but I don't see the point of the outer `while True` loop.  However, a good way of exiting your program is to use [`sys.exit`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

Comment: Hi, before this issue arrived I searched up on how to get my program to loop back to the beginning menu instead of exiting to make it more useful to the end user. This double While loop was a suggestion I found and it worked but causing the issue discussed in this post.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the double loop, but if it works for you, the `sys.exit` is probably your best bet. IanAuld's answer doesn't use a double loop and is the best overall solution.

Comment: Yeah I've since changed to Ian's answer hence it being marked as the solution to my problem. I totally forgot about defining a function. This is the suggestion I [found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907067/how-do-i-restart-a-program-based-on-user-input) for the double loop.