# Calling a function for a rematch?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def restart():
    import random
    import time

    opp = 0
    count = 0
    right = 0

    time.sleep (1.5)

    print ("E for easy, M for medium, H for hard!")
    time.sleep (1.5)

    choice = input("What do you choose?: ")
    print ("")

    if choice == 'E':
        print("You have chosen easy difficulty!")

    elif choice == 'M':
        print("You have chosen medium difficulty!")

    elif choice == 'H':
        print("You have chosen hard difficulty!")

    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        print ("")
        restart()

    time.sleep (2)
    print ("")
    print ("Are you ready?")
    print ("")
    time.sleep (2)
    print ("Lets go!")
    print ("")
    time.sleep (2)

    def rematch():
        if choice == "E":
            while (count <= 9):
                num1 = random.randint(1,5)
                num2 = random.randint(1,5)
                opp = random.randint(1,2)

                if opp == 1:
                    opp = ("+")
                elif opp == 2:
                    opp = ("-")

                print("what is " + str(num1) +  str(opp)  + str(num2)+ "")
                answer = (input("It is... "))

                if opp == "+":
                    qanswer = str(num1+num2)
                elif opp == "-":
                    qanswer = str(num1-num2)

                if answer == qanswer:
                    right = right + 1
                    print ("You got it right!")
                    time.sleep (1)
                    print ("")

                else:
                    print ("You got it wrong...")
                    time.sleep (0.5)

                    if opp == "+":
                        print ("The correct answer was " + str(num1+num2) + "")
                        print ("")
                    elif opp == "-":
                        print ("The correct answer was " + str(num1-num2) + "")
                        print ("")

                    time.sleep (1)
                count = count + 1

            print ("you got " + str(right) + " out of 10!")
            yeet = (input("Would you like to rematch, restart, or quit?: "))
            if yeet == ("restart"):
                print ("")
                restart()
            elif yeet == ("rematch"):
                print ("")
                rematch()
            elif yeet == ("quit"):
                print ("See you next time!")
                print ("")
                time.sleep (2)
                exit()
            else:
                print ("Invalid input,")
                time.sleep (1)
                print ("Please input either rematch, restart or quit")
```

At the end of this code, I call the `restart()` function to start it. The `restart` function definition also works in the "restart" selection at the end of the questionnaire. Though I have tried many times to make the defition of "rematch" both run at the start of the code by itself, it never does, stopping the code at the "are you ready?" print. On top of this I am trying to make it so that when someone types "rematch" the code restarts just from the definition. How could that be done?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: See the [mcve] guidelines -- a good code sample in a question will be the shortest possible thing that lets others reproduce a clear problem, with actual and desired output clearly distinguished. At least 90% of the code gives no appearance of having anything to do with the question.

Comment: As Linus Torvalds claims, "if you need more than 2 indents, you're screwed anyways". Break up your code into smaller portions!

Comment: ...that said, I wonder if this is a duplicate of [How do I restart a program based on user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907067/how-do-i-restart-a-program-based-on-user-input)

Comment: You never call `rematch` in `restart`. Why do you expect it to run?

Comment: At a minimum, you need to call `rematch()` from somewhere in `restart()` after you define `rematch()`. But it would probably be a good idea to move `rematch()` up to the same level as `restart()` and call it from `restart()` with the choice the user made. Beyond that ... it's not a good idea to call a function from itself the way these do -- you could eventually have so many copies running that Python crashes (e.g., if you restart 1000 times). Better to setup an outer loop that keeps calling `restart()` or `rematch()` until the program is done.

Answer (score 0):

Why use so many calls to `sleep`? this is not necessary.

I've cleaned up things a bit for you and made a minimal example that you can use to build on.
I've not implemented the difficulty levels; once you understand the basics of the program, you can try to implement it; my approach would be to link the difficulty level with the range of numbers randomly generated.

Have fun.

```
import random
import time


def start():
    global opp, count, right, choice

    opp = 0
    count = 0
    right = 0

    while True:
        choice = input("What difficulty do you choose? \n")
        try:
            print(f"You have chosen {difficulty[choice]} difficulty!")
            break
        except KeyError:
            print("please enter 'E', 'M', or 'H': ")

    print("Are you ready?")
    time.sleep (2)
    print("Lets go!")


def play():
    global opp, count, right, choice

    # if choice == "E":  # implement that later
    while count < 10:
        num1 = random.randint(1, 5)
        num2 = random.randint(1, 5)
        opp = random.choice(('+', '-'))

        print(f"what is {num1} {opp} {num2}")
        answer = input("It is... ")

        qanswer = str(num1 + num2) if opp == "+" else str(num1 - num2)

        if answer == qanswer:
            right = right + 1
            print("You got it right!")
        else:
            print("You got it wrong...")
            print(f"The correct answer was: {qanswer}")
        count = count + 1

        print(f"you got {right} out of 10!")

    yeet = input("Would you like to rematch (Y, N)?: ")
    if yeet == "Y":
        start()
    else:
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':

    difficulty = {'E': 'easy', 'M': 'medium', 'H': 'hard'}
    opp = 0
    count = 0
    right = 0
    choice = None

    start()
    play()
```