# How to restart my program with a button press 'r'?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7

Okay I've created Space Invaders in Python 3.7.4 and Pygame 1.9.6. I've got everything working no bugs or anything. I've even got the paused button to work great. It's just when the screen puts up 'GAME OVER' text to signify you lost. I would like to pop up a window to ask play again after the text goes away. But I just don't know where to begin at. I've looked at [How do I restart a program based on user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907067/how-do-i-restart-a-program-based-on-user-input) for help, but I couldn't understand where to implement it at or where to look at. This was my first real project/game I created in Pygame.

Code:

```
paused = False
running = True
while running:
    # RGB =  Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # Background Image
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:  # Pausing
                paused = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_u:  # Unpausing
                paused = False
    if not paused:
                '''The rest of the code, with the movement key presses, etc.'''
```

Since everything above the 'while running loop' is constantly being loaded or for data retrieval like the images the coordinates for where the images should be, the background music, etc. So I wanted it to be like the pausing/unpausing part of the code when I press down on say 'r'. I want to replay the program without exiting it. So I would be very grateful for help by people. Thank you all.

Comment: Try putting your while loop / variables that need to be reset into a function. To start the game the first time, you call that function, and then to restart it you can just call it again.

Comment: you can put code in `while`-loop - when you end game then set `running = False` and it will exit `while running` and go to external `while`-loop which will run all again and set values again. Of couse some elements you can set only once so you can do it before external `while`-loop

Comment: But wouldn't that only be called once when I restart it, but what if I want to do it again.

Comment: if you put code in `while` then it will run your `while running` many times. If you what to use function `reset()` then run it once before your `while running` and later use `reset()` inside `while` loop when you press `r`. In `reset()` you have to set only values which you want reset again when you restart game - you don't have to run again `pygame.init()`,  set `screen`, load images, but you have to reset score, player position, emeny position, etc.

Comment: But once the "GAME OVER" text appear I have it break the while loop.

Comment: you have to break only internal loop `while running` which should be inside external `while gaming` which will run game again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create function or methods in object to reset data and use it before every game. You can use external `while`-loop for this.

```
# executed only once
pygame.init()
screen = ...
# .. load data ...
player = ...
enemy = ...

gameing = True
while gameing:
    
    # reset data before every game
    player.reset()
    enemy.reset()
    score = 0
    
    paused = False
    running = True
    
    while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # exit game
                running = False
                gameing = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:  # restart game (but don't exit)
                    running = False
                    #gameing = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_x:  # exit game and program
                    running = False
                    gameing = False

        if game_over:  # restart game (but don't exit)
           running = False
           #gameing = True
```

You can also organize it as @Starbuck5 mentioned in commen - but then you should use `running` to exit program but not to exit game on game over

```
def reset():
    global score, paused, running

    player.reset()
    enemy.reset()
    score = 0
    paused = False
    running = True

# executed only once
pygame.init()
screen = ...
# .. load data ...
player = ...
enemy = ...

# (re)set data before first game
reset()    

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # exit game
            running = False
            gameing = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:  # restart game (but don't exit)
                #running = False  # DON'T DO THIS
                reset()

            if event.key == pygame.K_x:  # exit game and program
                running = False

   if game_over:  # restart game (but don't exit)
      #running = False  # DON'T DO THIS
      reset()
```

This need use `global` for every variable which you have to reset so it can be more useful when you have code in classes and you can use `self.` instead of `global`

Comment: You showing me it makes me understand it a whole lot better thank you so much. I'm not just going to copy and paste or whatever I will learn from this.