# How to restart and exit program using Enter and Esc buttons on keyboard?

Tags: python, loops, keyboard, calculator, enter

Basically I want to write at the end "Press Enter to restart the program or press Escape to quit the program. I want the code to understand what button the person is pressing so that it can either repeat the code or quit the program. How do I do that?

```
from math import *
import keyboard

print("Welcome to Calculator")
print("Choose an operation to perform:")
print("1. Addition")
print("2. Subtraction")
print("3. Multiplication")
print("4. Division")
print("5. Power")
print("6. Square Root")

operation = input()

if operation == "1":
    num1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter second number: ")
    result = float(num1) + float(num2)
    print("The result is " + str(result))
elif operation == "2":
    num1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter second number: ")
    result = float(num1) - float(num2)
    print("The result is " + str(result))
elif operation == "3":
    num1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter second number: ")
    result = float(num1) * float(num2)
    print("The result is " + str(result))
elif operation == "4":
    num1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter second number: ")
    result = float(num1) / float(num2)
    print("The result is " + str(result))
elif operation == "5":
    num1 = input("Enter the number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter the power: ")
    result = pow(float(num1), float(num2))
    print("The result is " + str(result))
elif operation == "6":
    num1 = input("Enter the number: ")
    result = sqrt(float(num1))
    print("The result is " + str(result))
else: print("Invalid Operation")


k = input("Press any button to exit")
```

Not the same as this code, since this code doesn't help with adding keyboard buttons, Enter and Esc

```
while True:
    # main program
    while True:
        answer = str(input('Run again? (y/n): '))
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        print("invalid input.")
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
        break
```

Comment: if you use `input()` then you can only catch `Enter` which will gives empty string. Mixing `input()` with `keyboard` is not good idea because `input()` will block code. Better search on internet function `getch()` or `getchar()` which can get single char without using `Enter` - and use it instead of `input()` - and it should gives you result when you press only `ESC` or `ENTER` or single number.

Comment: check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907067/how-do-i-restart-a-program-based-on-user-input/30247200)

Comment: if you put code in loop `while True` then you can repeate it again and again. And then you need `break` to exit this loop.

Comment: The one you gave me solves most of the problem, but it doesn't really show how to use the Keyboard buttons, Enter and Esc, to make the code detect it and then restart or exit accordingly.

Comment: @furas Sort of like this right?
`
while True:
        answer = str(input('Run again? (y/n): '))
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        print("invalid input.")
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
        break

Except it doesn't tell me how to use or detect the keyboard presses to make it happen.

Comment: put it in question - it will be more readable and other people will see it so other people may also help. BTW: `input()` always return string so you don't have to use `str()`. To make sure you could `strip()` spaces and convert to `lower()` because someone may put `Y`, `N` and accidently add some spaces/tabs which may not be visible for user.