# How can I get my code to restart based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python, and I wanted to be able to restart the program from scratch with a code. I don't know what code I am supposed to use for this, but this is what my script looks like, and what I am aiming at. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907067/how-do-i-restart-a-program-based-on-user-input/30247200), but it didn't help since I don't know that much.

```
name = input("What is your name? ")

print("Nice to meet you, " + name)


js = input("What is your weight you would like to convert from lbs to kg? ")

weight1 = int(js) * 0.453592
weight2 = str(weight1)

print("Converted weight: " + weight2)

restart = input("Would you like to restart the calculator (y/n)? ")

if "y" in restart:
    # Code to restart program?


if "n" in restart:
    print("Goodbye.")
```

What can I insert in the comment to make this restart from the top?

Comment: Put your main code into a function, then run the function when the user chooses to.

Comment: "I saw this, but it didn't help since I don't know that much." isn't something we can help you with, because there isn't a way to understand what's preventing you from applying the advice. A general technique is explained there, and all we can really do here is explain it again.

Comment: I just wanted to put this out there to see if someone can write a better code and if I can just copy and paste the code into PyCharm (which is what I use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your logic in a function.
then call the function in your if statement.

```
def getWeight(name):
    print("Nice to meet you, " + name)

    js = input("What is your weight you would like to convert from lbs 
    to kg? ")

    weight1 = int(js) * 0.453592
    weight2 = str(weight1)
    return weight2

if y:
   getWeight(name)
```