# How to make a return to menu option work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a menu where after selecting an option you are prompted with whether or not you want to return to menu. I used this code here from an old post (slightly modified from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30760917/17071504)), unfortunately it doesn't prompt the user asking to return to menu instead it just runs the first line of the program then stops.

```
def script():
    # program code here
    restart= (input("Would you like to return to menu?"))
    if restart == "yes" or restart == "y":
        script()
    if restart == "n" or restart == "no":
        print ("Thank you for using _______")
script()
```

If anyone could explain why it would only run the first line or how to fix it would be very grateful. (I would ask the commenter that i linked but unfortunately I'm very new to this and dont have the ability to)

Comment: "instead it just runs the first line of the program then stops." - does it give an error message or do what you want it to but without asking to restart?

Comment: Don't call `script()` recursively here. You could eventually hit a stack overflow. Use a `while True` loop instead, and break out of the loop when you don't want to re-show the menu. Also, please fix your code indentation.

Comment: @ChrisOram it doesnt give an error, it runs the first line of the program and then stops the same way it would if that was the end of the code.

Comment: It runs the first line of the program and then stops - do you mean it runs something in `# program code here` and never reaches the input then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not clearly state what issue are you facing..
`# program code here` doesnt showcase what program exists here. Will the following approach work:

```
def script():
    while (True):
        # program code here
        restart= (input("Would you like to return to menu?"))
        if restart == "yes" or restart == "y":
            continue
        if restart == "n" or restart == "no":
            print ("Thank you for using _______")
            break
script()
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I'll try to be clearer in future.